# Host Migration (P2P) with RTMFP and AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, udp, actionscript, peer-to-peer

I was wondering if this is a possibility with RTMFP since it acts like UDP/P2P..

Host Migration

1. Player A starts and host a game..
2. Player B and C connects..
3. Player A quits..
4. Player B is now assigned as new host/server
5. Game not interrupted or disconnected.

Maybe some basic example on how this is done with RTMFP/AS3?