# Electing a host with WEBRTC

Tags: javascript, networking, synchronization, peer-to-peer

This is similar to [Host Migration (P2P) with RTMFP and AS3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114711/host-migration-p2p-with-rtmfp-and-as3)

I have a webRTC chat room, initially used Twilio and switching to skyway, the situation is that I have a bunch of peers with data broadcast and there is a firebase datastore with the game state.

I want to elect a host and deal with the host dropping. Currently all the peers just running the same code, so I was thinking I could have the one with the lowest uid propose being the host and then get accepted.

How can I make this robust to race conditions?